# 体言止め can only be applied to サ変名詞 when する is just する (and not past or passive), right?

Tags: abbreviations

I am reading a document that has some normal 体言止め and want to review:

> 2021年度からaaaドームのネーミングライツ権を取得。

ok. Since **取得** is slated to happen in the future, **する** has been dropped. This is normal. Then, in the same document:

> 2018年秋にサービスを開始すると発表した。

Clearly, this **する** happened in the past and can only be inferred as **した** yet it is not dropped.

Next, here is chance for 体言止め with 受け身形 (passive) in the present tense:

> このapplicationで現在地を検索するには、GPSを用いた位置情報取得権限が要求される。

This only makes sense if 要求 is in the present tense in passive voice (される), but される is not dropped.

**question**
The rule of 体言止め with サ変名詞 is just that "する" can only be dropped if "する" is just "する", and not conjugated even if the context makes any conjugation (into past, passive, or causitive) 100% clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you don't *have to* use 体言止め. It's very common, but still is a kind of rhetorical device to make a sentence look more vivid, dramatic, concise, etc. Plain Japanese sentences usually do not use it.

You can safely use 体言止め for past (and active) actions. For example:

> 1995年、○○大学を卒業。1995年に○○商社に入社、○○事業部に配属。○○の研究開発に従事。2008年、退職。その後文筆家として活動。テレビにも多数出演。2015年○○大学講師に就任。

On the other hand, passive される *can* be dropped, but is relatively uncommon and should be used sparingly when space is really limited, like in news headlines.

> - 暴動で200人が逮捕
> - 霞ヶ浦のワカサギ漁が解禁

Even in headlines, usually active versions are preferred (e.g., 暴動で200人**を**逮捕). Often が is also omitted (e.g. 暴動で200人逮捕, 霞ヶ浦のワカサギ漁解禁), in which case it is hard to tell whether the verb is active or passive.

Comment: agreed. I've been picking Japanese docs off the web, assuming they are native and correct, and trying to 手本 it。not good. I've seen some pretty bad English out on the web myself. I'll be more careful what I try to read!