# Omitting the する after a する verb in formal writing

Tags: conjugations, formality

In reading several Japanese websites detailing how to write a Japanese resume, I ran across a pattern I found curious. There would be a sentence ending in a する verb used as a verb (i.e. with particles such as を or に), but without any following する or even だ or です. I feel like I saw this most in compact job description bullet points, but it also showed up in longer-form writing surrounded by です・ます sentences.

Here is an example from one website:

> ◯◯大学を卒業後、求人情報サイトを運営する株式会社◯◯に入社。営業職として、新規顧客の開拓を中心に取り組んでおりました。([source](https://employment.en-japan.com/tenshoku-daijiten/44323/))

I'd like to use this pattern myself as it feels less repetitive, but it conflicts with what I've learned, so I'm worried about seeming informal or inconsistent.

What is this pattern? In what contexts is it appropriate and what connotations does it have?

Comment: Related: [体言止め can only be applied to サ変名詞 when する is just する (and not past or passive), right?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77604/43676)

Comment: @aguijonazo Thank you! Just having a name for it really helped with my underlying question of "What is this thing and when can I use it?"