# What role does と play in 「無職42歳と断定説得を開始する」?

Tags: particle-と

What role does と play in

> 警視庁は犯人を音原田(おとはらだ)九郎(くろう)無職42歳と断定説得を開始するもようです

Comment: It is equivalent to ...と断定し、説得を...

Comment: Is it from Death Note? If it is a quote from a creative work, please provide the title and the author at least. If it's a visual art like manga, the layout can matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you hear a long pause between 断定 and 説得? It's essentially two sentences.

> 警視庁は犯人を音原田九郎、無職、42歳**と**断定(しました)。説得を開始するもようです。

Omission of する/しました is very common in news articles and such. See: [体言止め can only be applied to サ変名詞 when する is just する (and not past or passive), right?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77604/5010)

断定する is one of the [verbs that take arguments that look like `AをB(だ)と`](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010). AをBと断定する means "to judge/conclude (with 100% confidence) that A is B". So in short, と in bold is like "as" in English.

> 警視庁は犯人を音原田九郎、無職、42歳**と**断定(しました)。説得を開始するもようです。
> The Police Department identified the perpetrator **as** Kuro Otoharada, unemployed, age 42. They are going to start persuading him.